# Disable Eclipse validators and plugins?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use `eclipse Helios` with `Android SDK` and ... as ID for developing Android Apps.Recently it takes long time from starting eclipse to end of `building workspace`,for example in about 6 or 7 minutes.So I looked for ways to speed up Eclipse.I found some proposes,for example changing `eclipse.ini` and adding more memory,disabling startup automatic builds and ... .I did those successfully but I have a little probles with 2 other ways:

1. Disable Eclipse validators:
   I browse **Windows > Preferences** but I do not see any option in about **Validation**.
2. Disable Plugins:
   In eclipse I browse **Windows > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown** and there is list of plugins:

[image]

But I do not know which plugin can be disabled without causing any problem.
Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1):

1. To disable validators go windows>preferences and type "valida.." (filtering will work as you type) and uncheck the validators you want to deactivate.
2. You can disable Automatic Updates Scheduler and Mylyn plugins safely. Android development toolkit plugins are responsible for android development. Equinox Provisioning platform plugins are responsible to see if the required dependencies are exist when you want to install a new plugin. So killing p2 and android plugins is not a good idea.

Also I prefer adding memory (mx, ms, heap) and using following options which work on my installiation.
-XX:+AggressiveHeap
-XX:+UseParallelGC